# Are entities created with em.create managed and persisted?

Tags: mikro-orm

The documentation on https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager/ says

> An entity is managed if it’s fetched from the database (via em.find(), em.findOne() or via other managed entity) or registered as new through em.persist().

But it doesn't mention the `em.create` method.
Are entities created with `em.create` automatically managed, and would they be persisted by `em.flush`?
And if so, is it possible to create a entity that will not be persisted by `em.flush` with `em.create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is a shortcut for `EntityFactory`, all it does is to create the instance, just like if you used the entity ctor manually. It won't be persisted, neither managed (entity becomes managed *after* the flush call, perist itself is just for marking it).

```
// this is the same
const a = em.create(User, { name: '...' });
em.persist(a);
await em.flush();

// as this
const a = new User();
a.name = '...';
em.persist(a);
await em.flush();
```

In both examples, without the `em.persist` nothing would be stored in the db.